# Retagging question by 500+ user makes the Community reject an edit suggested earlier by another user

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

#### Time: 2013-01-31 11:03:29 UTC

I had [suggested this edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/78143). Me having less than 2000 Reputation sends this edit in Review Queue for approval of members with more than 2000 Repuatation.

#### Time: 2013-01-31 11:04:04 UTC

Another user with more than 500 Reputation but less than 2000 Reputation [edits the tags of the question - Revision 2](https://askubuntu.com/posts/249749/revisions). Since we get the [privilege to retag questions at 500 Reputation](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/retag-questions), this edit (retag) overwrites the edit suggested by me (sent for approval) - it shows as [Community](https://askubuntu.com/users/-1/community) rejected the edit.

---

This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This is not reproducible anymore since the retagging privilege was retired.

Comment: @Braiam: Instead of closing the question, it should be properly tagged as either [meta-tag:status-completed], [meta-tag:status-norepro], [meta-tag:status-bydesign] or whatever is appropriate. Moreover [tag:retagging] was appropriately used - I don't know why you keep removing tags from some of my questions :-)

Comment: Yeah, but those tags require mod action. I'm just doing what as a community member I can. About removing tags, check this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7819/could-we-get-rid-of-all-unuseful-tags-tags-that-alone-cant-be